# How to use Sort-Object on name with paren

Tags: powershell-2.0

I"m trying to sort the output from Get-Process, like this:

```
 Get-Process | where { $_.Name -Like "Chrome" } | Sort id  

 Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
```

Sorting by Id works as expected.  How do I specify 'CPU(s)'?  If I replace `id` with `CPU(s)`, I get an error:

> Get-Process | where { $_.Name -Like "Chrome" } | Sort CPU(s)
>   The term 's' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Thanks for any hints...

Comment: Tried this, but no joy:  Sort -property @{Expression="$_.CPU(s)";Descending=$true}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `CPU` without the `s`

```
Get-Process | where { $_.Name -Like "Chrome" } | Sort CPU
```

if you do

```
(Get-Process | where { $_.Name -Like "Chrome" } )[0] | FL *
```

You can have the right names in a list.
What you see normally is the [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) used by powershell command.

Comment: That renders the output of the first "chrome" process in a list.  Not really much like what I was trying to do:  Sort all the "chrome" processes by the CPU(s) column.

Comment: @Number8 As I wrote: use CPU , I edit my answer... for better explain what I mean

Comment: I thought I had tried `Sort CPU` and got an error, but it's working as expected now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Number8 Gald to help!